# Is information stored in OneNote online encrypted

Tags: onenote

Is information stored in www.onenote.com (OneNote Online) encrypted or can you force the information to be encrypted?  I like the idea of being able to access your information from any device, but a little hesitant about the kind of information to store if it is not encrypted or you cannot force the encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote supports adding another layer of security by password protecting a section ([More details](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Password-protect-your-notes-e5ffd8fd-e811-441a-aa02-e13f0f445933)).
Do note though that you have to use a desktop client one time to set the password. But once set, you can use OneNote Online to enter the password and access your notes.